# ¿Por qué no funcionan los update tras cargar una escena? Unity

Tags: unity

estoy finalizando un proyecto y me he dado cuenta que cuando cargo una escena por segunda vez (esta posee los assets por defecto de unity de jugadores en tercera persona y sus controles), estos no entran el el método update pero si en el start.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Intenta formular mejor la pregunta. Añade script del código que falla, el error/advertencia que muestra, algún síntoma, algo a lo que agarrarnos y poder ayudarte. Te dejo un enlace con [tips](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condiciona todo lo que el Update ejecutara.

```
void Update()
{
  if(!null)
  {
   ...        //Ejecución
  }
}
```

Esto puede suceder porque al reiniciar la escena, lo que haces es destruir todo y volver a instanciar, y a la velocidad de ejecución algo no te carga.

Comment: En efecto, al reiniciarla se destruía todo. Muchas gracias.